# Error while executing python script in aws code build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Requirement is that I need to execute a python script located in s3 bucket with passing environment in AWS code build.  Below is my buildspec file, while running give me error stating file format is not zip. When I uploaded code as zip file, again gives me error stating exit status code 1.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp s3://test bucket/code.zip .
      - unzip code.zip
  build:
    commands:
      - python code.py
```

Comment: Does the name of your bucket actually contain a space character, or did you just do that as an example in your question?